# Show specific xml layouts with only one java class

Tags: java, android, layout

I had a very similar problem before where i wanted to show random xml layouts. I've done that - with lots of help by Ben Williams - with a class named DisplayRandomPage.class and I had a main.xml layout with four buttons.

That's the code of the Main.class:

```
    switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.first_button:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstPage.class));
    break;
case R.id.second_button:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondPage.class));
    break;
case R.id.third_button:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ThirdPage.class));
    break;
case R.id.random_button:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayRandomPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and this is in the DisplayRandomPage.class:

```
    public class DisplayRandomPage extends Activity {

    private Integer [] mLinearLayoutIds = { 
    R.layout.one
    R.layout.two,
    R.layout.three
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 


Random random = new java.util.Random();
int rand = random.nextInt(3);

setContentView(mLinearLayoutIds[rand]);
        }
}
```

What i'd like to do is creating a DisplaySpecificPage.class. Above I've shown my main.class with the switch-case-clause. So when i click on the first button, it will start the FirstPage.class, clicking the second, it will start SecondPage.class, and so on. So for each xml-file i have to create a new java-class although the different java-classes do all the same. Only the xml-files are different. So i'd like to put something like this:

pseudo-code:

```
    case R.id.first_button:
startActivity(new Intent(this, DisplaySpecificPage.class)) with R.layout.first_page;
break;
```

how do i pass the ID from the layout (R.layout.first_page) on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `switch` statement to

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySpecificPage.class);
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.first_button:
        intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.one);
        break;
    case R.id.second_button:
        intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.two);
        break;
    case R.id.third_button:
        intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.three);
        break;
    case R.id.random_button:
        intent.putExtra("mylayout", randomNumber);
        startActivity(intent);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

This way you'd start the same activity no matter which button would be pressed, and inside the `DisplaySpecificPage` activity's `onCreate` method you should set the content to this passed layout:

```
final int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("mylayout", R.layout.one);
setContentView(layout);
```

The code above passes an extra parameter to the intent when starting the `DisplaySpecificPage` activity, with the name: "mylayout".

Inside the `DisplaySpecificPage` class' `onCreate` method you just retrieve this extra parameter using the `getIntExtra` method of the passed intent (`getIntent()` will return it for you), and you set the content view of this `DisplaySpecificPage` activity to the passed layout by `setContentView(layout)`.

You should make sure though, to always pass a valid layout identifier to that intent, otherwise you'll get exception when trying to inflate it (so `randomNumber` should be selected properly).

**Update**
With adding extras to the Intent you can parametrize your activities.

So using `intent.putExtra("paramName", paramValue)` you'll pass the `paramValue` value on the name of `paramName` to the activity you start by this intent.

You want to start the `DisplaySpecificPage` activity, but want it to have different layout based on which button you click. 
So you create an intent:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySpecificPage.class);
```

Before starting the activity by calling `startActivity(intent)`, you have to put this extra information inside the `intent`, so the `DisplaySpecificPage` activity to know which layout it should set as its content view:

So if you pressed the second button, you want the layout of your new activity to be the one defined by the `two.xml` inside your `res/layout` folder. It is referenced by as `R.layout.two` (which is a `static int` value).

```
intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.two);
```

This line puts the layout's value as an extra into the `intent` object, and now you can start the activity, the layout reference will be passed to it.

The "mylayout" is a name you choose for your parameter. It can be anything (valid), it will be used inside the `DisplaySpecificPage` activity to retrieve the layout's reference. It is retrieved by this name:

```
final int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("mylayout", R.layout.one);
```

The `getIntExtra` method gets the integer value from the `intent` which has the name "mylayout", and if it's not found, then it will return R.layout.one.

If you want to handle this case (when no parameter with name `mylayout` is set), you can write

```
final int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("mylayout", -1);
if (layout < 0) 
{
    //TODO: no layout reference was passed
}
```

Comment: Hi rekaszeru!

I just was gonna put an answer in but sadly cannot cause I'm a new user... Anyways what you posted works! Thanks for that! I do have one last question left. `final int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("mylayout", R.layout.one);`
Am I right that `R.layout.one` gets replaced by the layout of the button i press. Let's say i press the second button and in the case-clause i have put `intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.two);` am i right there? and last I'd like to know what `"mylayout"` is for? Big thanks again!

Comment: You should put instead of `R.layout.one` the layout you want the new activity to look like (so definitely not your button's layout, unless you change the new activity's onCreate method, and decide the new layout based on the layout of the clicked button, which would be strange... Then passing id's over layout referenves would be better solution).

Comment: please see my update for a bit more explanation. i hope you'll succeed :)

Comment: got it! (- sometimes comments do not have to be 15 characters long ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code:

Main.class:

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
public void change(final View view) {
    Intent intent2 = null;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySpecificPage.class);
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.first_button:
            intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.layout1);
            break;
        case R.id.second_button:
            intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.layout2);
            break;
        case R.id.third_button:
            intent.putExtra("mylayout", R.layout.layout3);
            break;
        case R.id.random_button:
           intent2 = new Intent(this, DisplayRandomPage.class);
           startActivity(intent2);
        }
    // if the Random button was not clicked, if-condition is true.
    if (intent2 == null)
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

DisplaySpecificPage.class:

```
    public class DisplaySpecificPage extends Activity{
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("mylayout", R.layout.one);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(layout);
        }
    }
```

DisplayRandomPage.class:

```
    public class DisplayRandomPage extends Activity {

private Integer [] mLinearLayoutIds = { 
        R.layout.layout1,R.layout.layout2,R.layout.layout3
        };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    Random random = new java.util.Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(mLinearLayoutIds.length);
    setContentView(mLinearLayoutIds[rand]);
    }
}
```

Big thanks to rekaszeru!